# Deep comparison of objects with lodash isEqual getting false positive

Tags: javascript, mapkit, lodash

I'm attempting to compare two arrays of objects, each array having two objects using lodash's `isEqual` method. The properties that are different are likely inherited. It falsely reports true. I also compared just the first element of the array (to only compare objects) and it also reports that they are equal:

[image]

Comparing these two arrays or the first element of each array with `isEqual` reports `true`. You can see that the coordinates in the points property are different, so why does it say they are equal? Is it because points is inherited? The object is a `polylineOverlay` described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkitjs/mapkit/polylineoverlay).

Also converting each one to a plain object always reports false even when they are the same (as far as I can tell).

The objects are shown in the image (`newRunInArrow` and `runInArrow`). The code is simple:

```
 const trueRunIn = settings.magneticRunIn + magVar;

  const boundingRegion = map.region.toBoundingRegion();

  const style = new mapkit.Style({
    lineWidth: 5,
    lineJoin: 'round',
    strokeColor: '#FFF',
  });
  const newRunInArrow = createArrow(boundingRegion, trueRunIn, style);

  const areEqual = isEqualWith(runInArrow[0], newRunInArrow[0])
    && isEqualWith(runInArrow[1], newRunInArrow[1]);
  console.log('areEqual', areEqual); // Returns true
```

or

```
  const areEqual = isEqualWith(runInArrow, newRunInArrow)
  console.log('areEqual', areEqual); // Returns true
```

Making the run in arrow

```
export function createArrow(
  boundingRegion: mapkit.BoundingRegion,
  runInHeading: number,
  style: mapkit.Style,
): mapkit.PolylineOverlay[] {
  const { smallestRadius, largestRadius } = getRadii(boundingRegion);

  const arrowLength = largestRadius / 3;
  const arrowPointLength = arrowLength / 4;
  const arrowOffset = largestRadius / 8;
  let arrowTipFromCenter = largestRadius - arrowLength - arrowOffset;

  if (arrowTipFromCenter + arrowPointLength > smallestRadius) arrowTipFromCenter = smallestRadius - arrowPointLength;

  const { center } = boundingRegion.toCoordinateRegion();

  const topOfArrow = computeDestinationPoint(
    { latitude: center.latitude, longitude: center.longitude },
    arrowTipFromCenter,
    runInHeading - 180,
  );

  const bottomOfArrow = computeDestinationPoint(topOfArrow, arrowLength, runInHeading - 180, 6371000);
  const corner1 = computeDestinationPoint(topOfArrow, arrowPointLength, runInHeading - 135);
  const corner2 = computeDestinationPoint(topOfArrow, arrowPointLength, runInHeading - 225);

  const points = [
    [
      new mapkit.Coordinate(bottomOfArrow.latitude, bottomOfArrow.longitude),
      new mapkit.Coordinate(topOfArrow.latitude, topOfArrow.longitude),
      new mapkit.Coordinate(corner1.latitude, corner1.longitude),
    ],
    [
      new mapkit.Coordinate(topOfArrow.latitude, topOfArrow.longitude),
      new mapkit.Coordinate(corner2.latitude, corner2.longitude),
    ],
  ];
  const newRunInArrow = [
    new mapkit.PolylineOverlay(points[0], {
      style,
    }),
    new mapkit.PolylineOverlay(points[1], {
      style,
    }),
  ];

  return newRunInArrow;
}
```

Comment: do your points have own enumerable properties?

Comment: can you paste you code here

Comment: Sure, added. It's pretty simply comparing the two objects shown in the picture, but I included how that object is made. I don't have my own enumerable properties. I'm unsure of what mapkit is doing though.

Comment: `const areEqual = isEqualWith(runInArrow,, newRunInArrow)` certainly won't work the way you expect--was that a typo?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I was changing my second more complex test (checking each index) to the simple one I originally tried (just the two arrays). Thanks

Comment: Are any of the mapkit (which this should be tagged with) functions async? Be careful using raw console output to vet data; it may not reflect values at the time of use.

Comment: At the time of use, the data was in the variables. They are not async functions. When I pause before the compare, I checked the data, stepped over isEqual, and it output true. isEqual does not check inherited properties which I think mapkit is inheriting from overlay and the properties I want checked, hence the true.